# Email's not working SMTP Magento 2.4.6+

Tags: email, smtp, 2.4.6-p3

There is an issue with trying to get email to work. I'm using a dedicated server with Ubuntu and tried different versions to include Magento 2.4.6+ or 2.4.7+ seeing if it was a version issue. I use Hover as my mail provider and filled out all of the **SMTP** information but nothing works. I can't send a contact form request, purchase confirmation and others.  This is one of two issues I need to solve to have everything working. Need some real help!